# How can you stop videos being stolen on website?

Tags: web, video, streaming

I'm currently planning to build a website for training videos, but the material will be costly and I want to avoid users from freely downloading videos.

I've seen some of the questions asked on here already but they all seem quite old, so maybe things have changed. Is there a way to stop this from happening or a service you can pay for?

Comment: What existing question did you find and does it work for you? A post being old doesn't mean that it's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing a video is downloading a video. So no, you can’t stop somebody from downloading it, if you want them to play it. For control of how it’s played after it’s downloaded, you need DRM. Many live video platforms have DRM options.